# PHP Takes few seconds to start running any script

Tags: php

I have PHP 5.2.17 and when I run any script, it takes ~3 seconds to load. If I run it on my laptop this delay isn't here.

For example a simple file which contains only this code will take 3 seconds to run, it's weird:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

I guess it comes from my php.ini, how to remove this delay ?

My php.ini: http://pastebin.com/NHgLr8JL

**Solution:** The delay was due to php_curl.dll extension enabled.

Comment: There is nothing in your `php.ini` file to indicate any delay as far as I can see. You *really* need to upgrade PHP.

Comment: What happen if you refresh the page? Still have the delay?

Comment: I execute it from cmd: "php helloWorld.php" or from PHP Designer run button.

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been in [End of Life](http://php.net/eol.php) for over 4 years. You really should consider upgrading for security reasons

Comment: And you are sure this is not simply the slow performance of that system at compilation time?

Comment: And what does run from my laptop means? One more thing, PHP is a scripting language, so it will not be compiled but rather interpreted.

Comment: @frz3993 That is not correct. PHP is a just-in-time compiler like most scripting languages these days.

Comment: Well I'm using php to do various files treatments locally, I do not use it for web purposes. But yeah I should try upgrade, I didn't yet because I'm scared new bugs appear in my scripts.

Comment: I don't think it's because of slow performance, it's just an echo, my PC is quad core 2.7 Ghz.

Comment: @arkascha that is not correct. A JIT compiler is an idea for PHP 6, for now an interpreter is used. https://wiki.php.net/ideas/php6?s[]=jit

Comment: Sylvain: Is it possible that the delay is not due to PHP, but due to network lag?

Comment: @CamilStaps That is interesting. I assume we refer to different stages of processing. I always understood that php compiles the source into some bytecode which can be cached and is then interpreted. That is at least how all php caches explain their way of working.

Comment: Hmmph, this usually happens on windows server.

Comment: As I said I run it locally with cmd or my IDE

Comment: @arkascha you're obviously more knowledgeable on this topic than me, I've never done anything that deep in the infrastructure. I only know that https://github.com/php/php-src has as title "The PHP interpreter". But you may be right that it's different for different stages.

Comment: try disabling the curl dll in your `php.ini` if you don't use it

Comment: But when I do this in my cmd prompt: "php helloWorld.php", isn't it true to say that helloWorld.php is compiled ?

Comment: yes thanks this delay was coming from curl ! you should post answer that I can validate.

Comment: @sylvain1264 Is it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's on windows 7 x64

Comment: @sylvain1264 If possible, check if the same happens in Safe Mode. Maybe it's anti-virus or something that's scanning every running program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `PHP` on windows loading some extension`dll` files might cause delay. Try to disable unused dll like `php_curl.dll` if you don't use `curl` in your script.